# Conway's Game of Life recursive step function

Tags: haskell

To help me begin to understand Haskell, I'm implementing Conway's Game of Life and ran into a snag in my step function trying to build a 2D list. Relevant definitions below:

```
data Cell = On | Off deriving (Eq, Show)

type Board = [[Cell]]
type Coord = (Int, Int)
type IndexedBoard = [[(Coord, Cell)]]

testBoard =     [[On, On,  On]
                ,[On, Off, On]
                ,[On, On,  On]]

numNeighbors :: Board -> Coord -> Int
-- Returns the number of live neighbors given a Board and a Coord on that board
-- assume this is implemented correctly, because it's a bunch of code
-- that you don't otherwise need to read, and it passes tests.

addIndexes :: Board -> IndexedBoard
addIndexes xs = [[((x,y), el) | (x,el) <- zip [0..] row] | (y,row) <- zip [0..] xs]
removeIndexes :: IndexedBoard -> Board
removeIndexes = map (map snd)
-- addIndexes testBoard is
-- [ [((0, 0), On), ((1, 0), On),  ((2, 0), On)]
--   ,((0, 1), On), ((1, 1), Off), ((2, 1), On)]
--   ,((0, 2), On), ((1, 2), On),  ((2, 2), On)] ]
-- and removeIndexes . addIndexes = id
```

My step function is where I'm having trouble. I'm not sure how to build the 2D list I expect without mutual recursion (which I'm trying to avoid arbitrarily).

```
step :: Board -> Board
step board = removeIndexes . step' . addIndexes $ board where
    step' :: IndexedBoard -> IndexedBoard
    step' [] = []
    step' ([]:rest) = step' rest
    step' (((coord, cell):restrow):rest) = [(coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)] : (step' (restrow:rest))
    newCell :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
    newCell 2 On = On
    newCell 3 _ = On
    newCell _ _ = Off
```

I expect the follow output from `step testBoard`:

```
[[On,  Off, On ]
,[Off, Off, Off]
,[On,  Off, On ]]
```

But am instead getting:

```
[[On],  [Off], [On]
,[Off], [Off], [Off]
,[On],  [Off], [On]]
```

I understand that's because my recursive case of `step'` gives `[(coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)] : ...`, but if I pull that out of the list I get the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( gameoflife.hs, interpreted )

gameoflife.hs:51:44: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘(Coord, Cell)’ with ‘[(Coord, Cell)]’
      Expected type: IndexedBoard
        Actual type: [(Coord, Cell)]
    • In the expression:
        (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)
        : (step' (restrow : rest))
      In an equation for ‘step'’:
          step' (((coord, cell) : restrow) : rest)
            = (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)
              : (step' (restrow : rest))
      In an equation for ‘step’:
          step board
            = removeIndexes . step' . addIndexes $ board
            where
                step' :: IndexedBoard -> IndexedBoard
                step' [] = []
                step' ([] : rest) = step' rest
                step' (((coord, cell) : restrow) : rest)
                  = (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)
                    : (step' (restrow : rest))
                newCell :: Int -> Cell -> Cell
                newCell 2 On = On
                newCell 3 _ = On
                newCell _ _ = Off

gameoflife.hs:51:96: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[(Coord, Cell)]’ with ‘(Coord, Cell)’
      Expected type: [(Coord, Cell)]
        Actual type: IndexedBoard
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘(step' (restrow : rest))’
      In the expression:
        (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)
        : (step' (restrow : rest))
      In an equation for ‘step'’:
          step' (((coord, cell) : restrow) : rest)
            = (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)
              : (step' (restrow : rest))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I know I can write `stepRow :: [Cell] -> [Cell]` that I can use to process a row at a time, then add those row-wise to the new board recursively (`step (row:rest) = [stepRow row] ++ step rest` or something similar), but since I know I can do it that way, and I don't know how I could do it this way, I'd rather avoid that arbitrarily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last equation for `step'` is wrong.

```
step' (((coord, cell):restrow):rest) = [(coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)] : (step' (restrow:rest))
```

For each cell in each row, you produce a new single-cell row as output. If you insist on writing all your recursion by hand, you can fix this by consing onto the first row returned by the recursive call, rather than creating a new row each time:

```
step' :: IndexedBoard -> IndexedBoard
step' [] = []
step' ([]:rest) = [] : step' rest
step' (((coord, cell):restrow):rest) = 
  let (row:more) = step' (restrow:rest)
  in ((coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell) : row) : more
```

However, there is a much better approach: all you are doing is trying to apply a function to each of the `(Coord, Cell)` pairs in your nested list, while maintaining the list's structure. But that's exactly what `map` is for! You should define a much simpler function that updates a single entry in the list, and then map it over all of them:

```
updateCell :: (Coord, Cell) -> (Coord, Cell)
updateCell (coord, cell) = (coord, newCell (numNeighbors board coord) cell)

step' :: IndexedBoard -> IndexedBoard
step' = map (map updateCell)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! Haskell is (so far) breaking my brain...

Answer (score 2):

For the actual question see amalloy's answer. This is a too-long-for-comment...

The whole idea of *adding indices and then random-accessing other cells* (as `numNeighbours` does) is pretty unidiomatic in Haskells. Indices always forget a lot of structural information, are unsafe, and in particular for lists very inefficient. And pretty unnecessary: all you're ever accessing is *direct neighbours*.

A much nicer approach is to generalise this idea of *mapping elements in their immediate environment*.

```
mapInEnvi :: (a -> a -> a -> r) -> [a] -> [r]
mapInEnvi f (a:b:c:l) = f a b c : mapInEnvi
...  †
```

The nice thing is how such a higher-order function composes: in your case you have a two-dimensional list, but you can basically just map in each direction independently:

```
step :: Board -> Board
step = mapInEnvi modRow
 where modRow above row below = mapInEnvi modCell $ zip3 above row below
       modCell (ne,e,se)
               (n ,m, s)
               (nw,w,sw) = case length $ filter (==On) [ne,e,se,n,s,nw,w,sw] of
          0 -> Off
          1 -> Off
          2 -> m
          3 -> On
          _ -> Off
```

Unlike the solution you were aiming for, this doesn't need to perform any direct position lookups, therefore the complexity is just *O* (*h* · *w*) instead of *O* (*h* · *w* · (*h* + *w*)) where *h* and *w* are the height and width of the board.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>In case of a finite-sized board it's a bit trickier – you'll need to decide what to do on the boundaries.</sub>

Comment: boy I don't grok any of that code. I'll have to take some time to figure out what `mapInEnvi` is doing, because I don't get it.